# Solidity - selfdestruct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, delegatecall, selfdestruct, callcode

I'm just wondering what would happen if I don't put a `selfdestrut()` method in my smart contract.

As I read from the Solidity documentation ([Self-destruct](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.11/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#self-destruct)):

> Even if a contract’s code does not contain a call to `selfdestruct`, it can still perform that operation using `delegatecall` or `callcode`.

But... does it mean that *anyone* could call `selfdestruct()` to *any* contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, means that if you use delegate call in your contract and the code at the target address contains a line with `selfdestruct(someaddress)`, this code will be executed in your contract context, effectively destroying your contract.

This means you should be careful when using `delegatecall` and only use it in contracts that you wrote or that you know well.

Hope this helps